# Error message: 'list' object is not callable in python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, permutation

I am working on cyclic crossover in Genetic algorithm. The idea is for a given parent `[4,1,6,2,3,5,8,9,7,10]`, `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` , I must obtain a child out of it.Could anyone tell me why it says, "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
" in the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import random
from itertools import cycle, permutations


def cx(individual):
    c = {i+1: individual[i] for i in range(len(individual))}
    cycles = []
    xx = sorted(individual)
    newArray = np.array([xx,individual])

    while c:
        elem0 = next(iter(c)) # arbitrary starting element
        this_elem = c[elem0]
        next_item = c[this_elem]

        cycle = []
        while True:
            cycle.append(this_elem)
            del c[this_elem]
            this_elem = next_item
            if next_item in c:
                next_item = c[next_item]
            else:
                break

        cycles.append(cycle)

    #return cycles
    return [[d[i] for i in range(len(d))] for l in permutations(newArray) for d in ({p[n]: n for s, p in zip(c, cycle({n: i for i, n in enumerate(s)} for s in l)) for n in s},)]

print (cx([4,1,6,2,3,5,8,9,7,10]))
```

I expect it to return `[[1, 2, 6, 4, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10], [4, 1, 3, 2, 5, 6, 8, 9, 7, 10]]`

Comment: What part of the code the message refer to?

Comment: when I uncomment the first return and comment the second return it works well. But obviously it provides only cycles. However I need child!!

Comment: `cycle = []` vs `from itertools import cycle`. You are using the same name for two objects.

Comment: Normally, this would be totally wrong, but notice how `cycle = []` is inside while loop while he tries to call the function from the outside of it? If you come from other languages you'd expect it to still work since block scope is a thing. Sadly, Python *DOES NOT* have such thing. Deal with it and properly name your variables, cycle and cycles aren't proper variable names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging 101:

```
1822:~/mypy$ python3 stack52920742.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stack52920742.py", line 32, in <module>
    print (cx([4,1,6,2,3,5,8,9,7,10]))
  File "stack52920742.py", line 30, in cx
    return [[d[i] for i in range(len(d))] for l in permutations(newArray) for d in ({p[n]: n for s, p in zip(c, cycle({n: i for i, n in enumerate(s)} for s in l)) for n in s},)]
  File "stack52920742.py", line 30, in <listcomp>
    return [[d[i] for i in range(len(d))] for l in permutations(newArray) for d in ({p[n]: n for s, p in zip(c, cycle({n: i for i, n in enumerate(s)} for s in l)) for n in s},)]
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

We want to see the traceback, not just the error message.  We need to know **WHERE** the error occurs, not just was it says.

The error means that some variable, which has a `list` value, is being treated as though it is a function.  That is, a list is followed by `(...)`.  Lists aren't functions, they aren't `callable`.  They can only be indexed, which in Python uses the `[]` syntax.

A likely candidate is

```
cycle({n: i for i, n in enumerate(s)} for s in l)
```

Which looks like it's calling a `cycle` function, with a tuple of dictionaries.  But if `cycle` was a list, it would produce this error.

What's `cycle`?

```
from itertools import cycle
```

but also

```
cycle = []
```

Evidently the second assignment is overwriting the first.

If I rename that inner `cycle` to something like `alist`, it runs, though the print is

```
[[], []]
```

`cycles`, before the long `return`, is

```
[[4, 2, 1], [6, 5, 3], [8, 9, 7], [10]]
```

Why does `cx` go to all the work the create this `cycles` list, and then never use it?

Did you just copy the function from someplace, but not debug it?